# Symfony2 repository standard folder or namespace

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, doctrine-orm

I am creating a Repository to use it with an Entity in a Symfony2 project, but I do not know where to store the class. I have been researching in Internet but I do not have any info about the default namespace o default folder to store the Repositories.

I could "think" in two approaches:

1. use Entity folder: (entity and entityRepository in the same folder)

   /project/bundle/entity;
2. use Repository folder: (entity in entity folder and repository in Repository one)

   /project/bundle/entity;
   /project/entity/repository;

**There are any standard about that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store them anywhere you want, but the official Symfony [book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) uses

Acme/DemoBundle/Repository/

So I think that would be the more standard way

Comment: Is this still true. I don't see this on the current or previous book versions.

Comment: This is no longer the official Symfony way.  As can be seen here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes you would make use of the "Acme/DemoBundle/Entity" folder instead of the "Acme/DemoBundle/Repository/"

Comment: No longer the case. Offical docs say keep them in the Entity folder. For src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php you have src/AppBundle/Entity/ProductRepository.php  (Checked starting 2.7 up to Symfony 3.0)

Answer (score 1):

If somehow Symfony won't find your repository, you can use annotation at entity class to define specific repository namespace\class (in example: "Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Repository\MyEntityRepository") like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
*@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
*/
class MyEntity { ... }
```

Maybe it can be defined through YML, XML or PHP but I use annotations at entities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now reading a tutorial about How to create a blog with Symfony2 and there they have a Repository directory where store all the repository classes like this: src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Repository/BlogRepository.php I don't know if this is the best solution, but hope it helps. If you want to have a look at the tutorial - it's here - http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html

Answer (score 0):

Without wishing to through a spanner in the monkey, the Doctrine entity generator creates the repository classes in the Entity folder:

`php app/console doctrine:generate:entity`

**Entity:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Test
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\TestRepository")
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * TestRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class TestRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

Comment: you know you added the same thing twice, under entity and repository?